# List Ruby file in the directory using interactive ruby (irb)

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby language. I want to list the ruby file in the folder. When I use ls, the following error comes up. (By the way, I use pc, not Mac. What command line should I use to get ruby file in the directory? Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to do, can you post your code or a little more about what you want to accomplish. Do you want to list like `dir` does, but from your ruby code?

Comment: I use mac os and `option + tab` shows all the files in current directory, from irb console.

Answer (score 2):

To list the ruby files (files with `.rb` extension) using ruby code you can use [Dir.glob](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob)

```
Dir.glob('*.rb')
```

The documentation has other examples, such as getting all files with `.rb` extension in nested folders:

```
Dir.glob('**/*.rb')
```

Comment: Thanks both Jay and JP! Dir.glob('**/*.rb') - it works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the working directory you want to list files in, you can execute this in your ruby code:

```
Dir.entries(".")
```

Comment: irb(main):001:0> Dir.pwd
=> "C:/Ruby25-x64/bin"
irb(main):002:0> Dir.chdir ('D:\Udemy|ruby-learn to code')
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
        2: from (irb):2
        1: from (irb):2:in `chdir'
Errno::EINVAL (Invalid argument @ dir_s_chdir - D:\Udemy|ruby-learn to code)
irb(main):003:0>  Dir.chdir ('D:\Udemy\ruby-learn to code')
=> 0
irb(main):004:0> Dir.pwd
=> "D:/Udemy/ruby-learn to code"
irb(main):005:0> Dir.glob('*.rb)
irb(main):006:1' Dir.entries(".")
irb(main):007:1'

Comment: Thanks JP Silvashy. I am following along Learn to code with Ruby (Udemy course).

Comment: I want to list ruby file using Interactive Ruby (irb). I can change directory using Dir.chdir (file location). However I cannot list ruby file in the directory. I have tried your recommendation and Jay's - Dir.glob('*.rb'). Another thing I cannot do is clear. When I use gitbash, I can use clear and cls in command line, to clear what I have written before. Thank you very much.

Comment: @suwincoding, i'll add that you won't typically be navigating the filesystem inside your IRB console. But it's good to know how Ruby has access to some system commands like these.